# Finding minimum in the second column of the tuple in a nested list with integer and tuples

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, list-comprehension, nested-lists, minimum

I have a nested list of integers and tuples:

```
orders = [[1, ('5464', 49.96), ('8274', 233.82), ('9744', 404.55)]
          [2, ('5464', 99.91), ('9744', 404.55)]
          [3, ('5464', 99.91), ('88112', 274.89)]
          [4, ('8732', 93.93), ('7733', 208.89), ('88112', 199.75)]]
```

I want to get the minimum(output):

```
[(1, '5464')
 (2, '5464')
 (3, '5464')
 (4, '8732')]
```

How do I get the output using only list comprehension(no loops and other functions)?

```
My try:
p = [[x if type(x) != tuple else min(y[1:])[1] for x in y] for y in orders]
print(p)

output:
[[1, 49.96, 49.96, 49.96], [2, 99.91, 99.91], [3, 99.91, 99.91], [4, 208.89, 208.89, 208.89]]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use slices to separate the first element from the rest of the elements in each of the inner lists. Note that *every element of `orders` is a `list`*, so no typechecking should be required. We can use a slice to separate the first element from the rest of the elements, since the first element is different.

So, in the list comprehension, we output a tuple, where, for each list `lst` contained in `orders`, we

- Use `lst[0]` as the first element in our tuple
- take the `min(lst[1:])` of the remainder of `lst` (of course, you can use a custom `key` here if you'd like). This will produce a 2-tuple like `('5464', 49.96)`

  - Take the `[0]`th element of that, which would be `'5464'` in this example.

This produces the output you're looking for:

```
orders = [
    [1, ('5464', 49.96), ('8274', 233.82), ('9744', 404.55)],
    [2, ('5464', 99.91), ('9744', 404.55)],
    [3, ('5464', 99.91), ('88112', 274.89)],
    [4, ('8732', 93.93), ('7733', 208.89), ('88112', 199.75)],
]
output = [(lst[0], min(lst[1:])[0]) for lst in orders]
print(output)
# [(1, '5464'), (2, '5464'), (3, '5464'), (4, '7733')]
```

Comment: Hi, the output of `4` is not the expected output.

Comment: Why is that, the 4th element is the max and not the min? The list comprehension look right tho.

Comment: I got the solution which prints the correct 4th element, outplut = [(lst[0], min(lst[1:], key=lambda x:x[1])[0]) for lst in orders]